# .htaccess MOD_REWRITE specific cases

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am really struggling with `.htaccess` since I can't figure out how the syntax actually works and what the commands are. Let me describe what I need to achieve and maybe someone could guide me to the right answer:

I have a website which works with `JQuery Ajax`. So there is one single index.php file in the root folder. Any request of a sub-page via internal link(mysite.com/contact.php) is going through Ajax and the content information gets loaded from a folder called "/pages/" to the index.php.

But if a user enters the url itself (mysite.com/content.php) Everything breaks since the directory actually doesn't exist. Remember the content files are inside /pages/. And a direct access to the raw content files would not display the site, but only the information in raw form.
To solve this I started using .htaccess to pass not existing directory request to php, which passes it to Ajax. But here I got stuck. I am really bad with .htacces. This is what I got from the internet:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works for the most part, except if the request goes through a subfolder (mysite.com/download/version1)

So here is what I need .htaccess to do:

- Don't care if it is a folder or a file request, pass it to php.
- (optional) Do not allow direct access to /pages/ folder, but do allow if request comes via Ajax
- Do not mess up request calls for resource files. (This is important. When I fiddled around, I got many errors since .htaccess was also interfearing in resource file (.css/.js/.png) calls)

Feel free to take a look at the website trough: [GitHub](https://github.com/Haeri/paint.net-mock-up-page)

*The php part is inside index.php. The Ajax is done in PageHandler.js*

Comment: *"Do not allow direct access to /pages/ folder, but do allow if request comes via Ajax"* - There is no way of telling whether a request *really* came through Ajax. Every information you get from the client is easily spoofed. Don't build security features around spoofable information.

Comment: Your code will work with subdirectories if you add a leading slash `/` before `index.php?url=$1` in your rule. For your other question, you can't make a difference between ajax request or client request

Comment: You must use **absolute** paths instead of **relative** paths for your html links (css, javascript, images, link href)

Comment: So I have changed every directory to have a "/" infront. and now things are working again.. except: The url bar gets sticky subfolders.. meaning if I go to "mysite.com/foo/bar" the /foo sticks. if i change to download it says "mysite.com/foo/downlaod" and this goes on. If I visit the site "/download/v1" multiple times i get this "mysite.com/download/download/download/v1"...

Comment: Like i said, you must use absolute paths for everything. Your links (href) including

Comment: can you give me an example of an "absolute" link?